# Creating scrollable list with infinite-scroll in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, infinite-scroll

How can i create a list that is scrollable without scrollbars, and has infinite-scroll functionality?
i have tried the attached code but i have two problems with it:
1. the list is not being scrolled at all, unless i add `style="overflow-y: auto"` to the content, and then scrollbar is displayed.
it is not scrolled even if i add ion-scroll inside/outside the content.
2. when i add the overflow-y and scrollbar is displayed, the infinite-scroll does not work. the ionInfinite event is not fired.

Thanks.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list [style.direction]="direction">
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let item of selectedEntItems | objToIterable;let ind=index">
        <!--List item header-->
        <ion-card-header  *ngFor="let column of columns | objToIterable"  (click)="ListItemClick(item,ind)"  [ngClass]="{'hide': notHeaderColumn(item,column) ,'ListItemHeader':true}" >
              <span>
                {{ column.title + ': ' + getVal(item,column)}}
              </span>
              <span >,</span>
        </ion-card-header>

        <!--List item content-->
        <ion-card-content *ngFor="let column of columns | objToIterable" (click)="ListItemClick(item,ind)" [ngClass]="{'hide': notBodyColumn(item,column) }">
           <p> {{column.title + ': ' + getVal(item,column)}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
        <ion-icon name="close" (click)="deleteRow(item,ind)" class="listDelete"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)"> 
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```